# How to implement SOAP DoS prevention in Java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-security, microservices

the technology stack in our company are:

```
Java, Spring MVC, Spring Boot, Jaxws etc..
```

and we provide webservices for the client to querying our services.

in terms of securing the SOAP service. some of the webservices uses spring **OAuth** security and some of them uses the Spring **Basic Auth**

recently one of the client flooded our server by sending huge amount of request in the short period of time.

we are going to implement something to provent this to happen. ideally a 
per client based calling interval. which can recognize the high calling frequency. then **ban the client**  or force the **client to wait**

before we code this from the scratch, I wonder if there are libraries we can reuse. Spring normally very good at providing solutions for most of the enterprise issues. but so far I have't found any thing. any hint, ideally a working sample. would be great!

EDIT1: ideally we want to implement this instead of fully rely on the HTTP server e.g tomcat or apache to handle this. because our own implementation would offer more fine grained rules, such as how long the interval should be, 
what kind of customised message we can return, more important we can implement our own monitoring mechanism, and treating different client with different traffic allowance etc...

Comment: Did you thought about handling those issues with your "front" (http server like nginx/apache2). Since this has nothing to do with the business your application is designed for, you don't want to have all this technical code in your app.

Comment: Take a look at `RateLimiter` from `com.google.guava`.

Comment: @AkliREGUIG see update please.

Comment: @chimmi yeh,thanks. the RateLimiter could help but its just backed by a standard java lock.  I am looing for a framework ideally.

Comment: @JunchenLiu Combined with an interceptor and couple other small things it works fine for me for the exact same issue.

Comment: @JunchenLiu ok i see.

Comment: Did you consider putting an API Gateway in front, like Apigee (so Google nowadays) or AWS API GW? This should give you scale to manage any DoS attack (intentional or not intentional), give request throttling and in the future ease the pain of managing API versions.

Comment: @LechMigdal most valiable comment so far